# PL/SQL - how to repeat alternating text for a given number of times with a final output?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to make a procedure called OE that will have text output based on the number that I define.

For example, inputting the number 6 will give the following output:

```
odd
even
odd
even
odd
even
= even steven!
```

and inputting the number 5 will give the following output:

```
odd
even
odd
even
odd
= you oddball!
```

I'm completely new at this and have been struggling to get the odd number to load correctly (for some reason, it gets stuck in an infinite loop). Any help would be appreciated! Here is what I got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure oe
(p_n IN number)

AS
v_n number;
v_on number;

BEGIN
v_n := p_n;
v_on := p_n;

IF v_n>0 THEN LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('odd');
v_n := v_n-1;
dbms_output.put_line('even');
v_n := v_n-1;
If v_n=0 then
    exit;
    if v_on mod 2 > 0 then dbms_output.put_line('=' || ' you oddball!');
        exit;
        else
        dbms_output.put_line('=' || ' even steven!');
        exit;
        end if;
end if;
end loop;   
end if;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using exit conditions properly hence your code is going in infinite loop. You simplify your logic as below. Let me know it it works for you.
You may add few validations to make sure you get proper input parameters such as p_n > 0 and other.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure oe
(p_n IN number)
AS
begin
for i in 1..p_n
loop
if mod(i,2)=1 then dbms_output.put_line('odd');
else dbms_output.put_line('even');
end if;
end loop;
if mod(p_n,2)=1 then dbms_output.put_line('= you oddball!');
else dbms_output.put_line('= even steven!');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm -- I learned so much from your answer, thank you! Turns out I was a little overzealous with my exit conditions and I did not completely understand when to declare a variable. The FOR LOOP is definitely helpful -- thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

hemalp108 has already answered this, but I just wanted to add that you don't even need the `if/else` logic that fills the procedure (except perhaps for handling values less than 1, which I'll leave as an exercise), because we have `case`:

```
create or replace procedure oe
    ( p_n in number )
as
begin
    for i in 1 .. p_n loop
        dbms_output.put_line(case mod(i,2) when 1 then 'odd' else 'even' end);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line(case mod(p_n,2) when 1 then '= you oddball!' else '= even steven!' end);
end;
```

(You may also notice how laying your code out neatly is half the way towards debugging it.)